# How can I query this poorly designed SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I need help coming up with a query that will allow me to search against a SQL table that has been *very* poorly designed.

The table contains various attribute data for certain items. The problem is that the table is laid out like this:

```
serial#     attr        val
---------------------------
num         attr1       value
num         attr2       value
num         attr3       value
```

Multiple rows referring to the same item, but each row contains a different attribute value. **Before you start on me, I did not create this table.** I realize the attribute values should be column headers, among other things. Unfortunately, this is what I have to work with.

What I need to do is write a query to search this table for a given, specific item name (another attribute, stored in its own table row) based on multiple attribute criteria.

My idea so far, since the 'serial#' value is constant for a given item, is to write a query that would "cascade" from one attribute value to the next, but I'm  not sure how to do that, or even if that's the most efficient way. I've tried a "union" statment, such as

```
select serial# from [table] where attr = 'attr1' and val = 'value'
union
select serial# from [table] where attr = 'attr3' and val = 'value'
```

... but all that does is run each select statement individually, so I end up with serial# values where attr1 may match my search value, but attr3 may not, and vice versa.

So I need to return the 'name' attribute value where both attr1 and attr3 (and whatever other parameters I may need to include) all match the search criteria. Is there a way to do this? I am using Sql Server 2008 R2, fyi.

Comment: The easiest way would be `INTERSECT` but afaik SS2008 doesn't support it. If all those conditions are ANDed you can do self-JOINs, adding another join for a new condition.

Comment: @dnoeth It turns out that SS 2008 R2 does, in fact, support intersect. I didn't know that it would, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `intersect` to get the items which have both the attributes.

```
select serial# from [table] where attr = 'attr1' and val = 'value'
intersect
select serial# from [table] where attr = 'attr3' and val = 'value'
```

Or it could be done with a `having` clause.

```
select serial# 
from [table] 
group by serial# 
having sum(case when attr = 'attr1' and val = 'value' then 1 else 0 end)
     + sum(case when attr = 'attr3' and val = 'value' then 1 else 0 end)
      > = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another couple of possible solutions, depending on how many items you might be searching by:

```
SELECT [serial#]
FROM
    My_Table T1
WHERE
    attr = 'attr1' AND val = 'value1' AND
    EXISTS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM My_Table T2
        WHERE
            T2.[serial#] = T1.[serial#] AND
            T2.attr = 'attr2' AND
            T2.value = 'value2'
    )
```

Or:

```
SELECT [serial#]
FROM
    My_Table T1
WHERE
    (T1.attr = 'attr1' AND T1.value = 'value1') OR
    (T1.attr = 'attr2' AND T1.value = 'value2')
GROUP BY
    [serial#]
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2
```